# joint probability density: how to find the upper and lower bound in integration?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If the joint probability density of X and Y is given by

$$  f(x,y)= \begin{cases}
2(x^2-xy)  && \text{ for } 0 <x<1,-x<y<x\\ 
 0 && \text{elsewhere}\\
\end{cases} $$
and asking to find P(x+y<0.5)

as shown in the graph boundaries show be like this
[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2OLQ.png)

$$\int\limits_{0}^{1/2}\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}-y}cxy^2(1-x)(1-y^2)\, dxdy = 1$$

but I am confuse because y depends on x, so it shouldn't be like this.

any explanation ?

thank you

Comment: Can you explain what you mean when you say "I am confused because $y$ depends on $x$, so it shouldn't be like this"? What seems wrong to you?

Comment: I mean since -x<y<x and 0<x<1 can I take the boundaries from 0 to 1/2? .. I'm not sure of my procedure @AaronMontgomery

Comment: I have not verified your calculations, but having $x$ depend on $y$ rather than the other way around is not automatically a problem. In 2-dimensional integration problems, you can choose which variable should be the inner or outer limit of integration based on whatever is convenient for your region; often, either order of integration is acceptable (though one route may be more work or more difficult than the other). But there's no reason for concern just because the dependency is backwards relative to the problem statement.

Comment: Your graph only includes the condition and does not show the support.  Nor does it extend down to negative $Y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to integrate over the intersection of $0<x<1$, $-x<y<x$, and $x+y<1/2$.

Because $y$ may be negative, then $x$ may be greater than $1/2$.  Indeed when $x=1$, then $-1<y<-1/2$ is in the interval.

So the outer integration is over all of $x\in[0;1]$ and the inner is over $y\in[-x;\min\{x,1/2-x\}]$.

$$\int_0^1\int_{-x}^{\min\{x,1/2-x\}} 2(x^2-xy) \,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx$$

You can split this into a sum of two integrals, one over $x\in[0;1/2)$ and the second over $x\in[1/2;1]$.

Comment: thanks for your help ;)